# Reduce returns empty array, however scan does not

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming

Code:

```
const Rx = require('rxjs')

const data = [
    { name: 'Zachary', age: 21 },
    { name: 'John', age: 20 },
    { name: 'Louise', age: 14 },
    { name: 'Borg', age: 15 }
]

const dataSubj$ = new Rx.Subject()
function getDataStream() {
    return dataSubj$.asObservable().startWith(data);
}

getDataStream()
    .mergeMap(Rx.Observable.from)
    .scan((arr, person) => {
        arr.push(person)
        return arr
    }, [])
    .subscribe(val => console.log('val: ', val));
```

Using .reduce(...) instead of .scan(...) returns an empty array and nothing is printed. The observer of dataSub$ should receive an array.
**Why does scan allow elements of data to pass through, but reduce does not?**
Note: I am using mergeMap because I will filter the elements of the array before reducing them back into a single array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**scan** emits the accumulated value on every source item.

**reduce** emits only the last accumulated value. It waits until the source Observable is completed and only then emits the accumulated value.

In your case the source Observable, which relies on a subject, never completes. Thus, the **reduce** would never emit any value.

You may want to apply the reduce on the inner Observable of the **mergeMap**. For each array, the inner Observable would complete when all the array items are emitted:

```js
const data = [
  { name: 'Zachary', age: 21 },
  { name: 'John', age: 20 },
  { name: 'Louise', age: 14 },
  { name: 'Borg', age: 15 }
]

const dataSubj$ = new Rx.Subject()
function getDataStream() {
  return dataSubj$.asObservable().startWith(data);
}

getDataStream()
  .mergeMap(arr => Rx.Observable.from(arr)
    .reduce((agg, person) => {
      agg.push(person)
      return agg
    }, [])
  )
  .subscribe(val => console.log('val: ', val));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.js"></script>
```